# Grid Layout for Ionic using AngularJs, placing button in 4x3 rows and column for a jSon data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
Please help:
Would like to place buttons for a jSon data, 4 rows and 3 column(total 12 buttons) with 
   1) button name:  as jSon key ex "jan" etc (button names from Jan to Dec) 
   2) button color: blue for jSon value=="Yes" and red when value=="No".  Also,
```

Data as follows:
    var data ={
      "Jan":"Yes",
      "Feb": "No",
      "March": "Yes",
      "April": "No",
      "May": "Yes",
      "June": "No",
      "July": "Yes",
      "Aug": "No",
      "Sept": "Yes",
      "Oct": "No",
      "Nov": "Yes",
      "Dec": "No"
    }

```
</ion-content>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" > 
       <div ng-if="$index%4==0" class="row">
            <div class="col">

                    <span ng-if="value=='Yes'" >
                        <button id={{$index}} class="button button-royal" >{{key}}</button>
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="value=='No'" >
                        <button id={{$index+}} class="button button-assertive" >{{key}}</button>
                    </span>

                        <span ng-if="value=='Yes'" >
                            <button id={{$index+1}} class="button button-royal" >{{key[$index+1]}}</button>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="value=='No'" >
                            <button id={{$index+1}} class="button button-assertive" >{{key[$index+1]}}</button>
                        </span>

                            <span ng-if="value=='Yes'" >
                                <button id={{$index+2}} class="button button-royal" >{{key[$index+2]}}</button>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-if="value=='No'" >
                                <button id={{$index+2}} class="button button-assertive" >{{key[$index+2]}}</button>
                            </span>

                                <span ng-if="value=='Yes'" >
                                    <button id={{$index+3}} class="button button-royal" >{{key[$index+3]}}</button>
                                </span>
                                <span ng-if="value=='No'" >
                                    <button id={{$index+3}} class="button button-assertive" >{{key[$index+3]}}</button>
                                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0"> 
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < 12">
            <button ng-class="(datas[$index].color=='Yes'? 'button button-positive' : 'button')">{{datas[$index].month}}</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < 12">
            <button ng-class="(datas[$index+1].color=='Yes'? 'button button-positive' : 'button')">{{datas[$index+1].month}}</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < 12">
            <button ng-class="(datas[$index+2].color=='Yes'? 'button button-positive' : 'button')">{{datas[$index+2].month}}</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < 12">
            <button ng-class="(datas[$index+3].color=='Yes'? 'button button-positive' : 'button')">{{datas[$index+3].month}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### controller

```
$scope.datas = [{ "month":"Jan","color":"No"}, 
                    {"month":"Feb","color":"Yes"},
                    {"month":"March","color":"No"},
                    {"month":"April","color":"No"},
                    {"month":"May","color":"No"},
                    {"month":"June","color":"Yes"},
                    {"month":"July","color":"No"},
                    {"month":"Aug","color":"Yes"},
                    {"month":"Sept","color":"Yes"},
                    {"month":"Oct","color":"No"},
                    {"month":"Nov","color":"Yes"},
                    {"month":"Dec","color":"Yes"},
                    ];
```

Comment: Hi Paresh, thanks for reply.  
Plz note that I get data from outside services and it will always be in key/value as follows:
$scope.data={
        'key4': 'yes',
        'key1': 'no',
        'key3': 'yes',
        'key2': 'no',
        'key5': 'yes'
  ..... :  ....
  ..... :  ....
  ..... :  ....
  
    };
 
Please arrange your html code, 
where buttons name as "key" and button color as "value" (color blue for 'yes' and red for 'no')

Being new to client-Side, looking forward your help

Comment: plz note that $scope.data is a jSon Object holding key/value pair and NOT  a jSonArray holding objects. This data is from REST services and need to work on its format ie jSonObject and not jSon Array.